# Синус и косинус получают значение не в радианах, но при этом работают / C# WinForms

Tags: c#, математика

Решил попробовать сделать программу, рисующую пятиугольник в picturebox.
Сначала не понимал, почему рисунок не рисовался. Но когда убрал преобразование в радианы, пятиугольник начал нормально рисоваться. Почему код ниже работает нормально?

```
        {
                f = 90;
                Graphics graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
                Point[] points = new Point[6];
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                        points[i] = new Point(
                        x: (int)(150 + 100 * Math.Cos((f + (2 * Math.PI * i) / 5))), 
                        y: (int)(150 + 100 * Math.Sin(f + (2 * Math.PI * i) / 5)));
                }
                graphics.DrawLines(pen, points);
        }
```

Comment: Может, вы в радианы как-то не так переводили? просто сейчас у вас f — начальная точка, а потом вы пытаетесь нарисовать пятиугольник, нет? (Просто для i=0 и i=5 вершины у вас совпадает...) Ну, а стартовая точка у вас теперь с углом 2,04 радиана примерно, 116 градусов.

Comment: вершины и должны совпадать, для этого и сделано 6 точек. Т.к. до 6-й не рисует. Если сделать 5 точек, то нарисует только 4 грани. В радианы вроде правильно переводил, можете предложить свой вариант?

Comment: Разобрался, @Harry спасибо, в 6 утра не заметил, что привожу и f к радианам :D Но вопрос актуален - почему работает даже без радиан?

Comment: Чтобы принять наиболее полезный ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 5):

Косинус в `.net` считает углы в радианах.

В вашем коде смешаны углы двух видов: у вас `f` в градусах, а `2*PI/5` - в радианах.

Вам нужно `f` инициализировать как `PI/2`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> f + (2 * Math.PI * i) / 5
> ```

Начальный угол плюс 1/5 окружности, которая задана в радианах.
Такой код всегда даст пятиугольник, независимо от началоьного значения.

```
90 % (2 * PI) = 2.0354056994857928
90 % (2 * PI) / PI * 180 % 108 = 8.620156177409072
90 % (2 * PI) / PI * 180 % 108 + 108 - 90 = 26.620156177409072
```

Просто пятиугольнок будет на 26 градусов неправильно повёрнут.

Answer (score 0):

Для новичков, которые возможно как я тупанут: программа итак должна нормально работать, просто из-за того что программа принимает другое число, пятиугольник будет рисоваться под углом.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/692838)

Comment: @Harry, является же.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот у Pak Uula, например — полый ответ. Это же просто комментарий. IMHO.